# JS: Exclude HTML tag from replace();

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to exclude `<img>` and `<a>` tags from this very short script but it just completely ignores `.not('img')`.

My code:

```
$('body').children().not('img', 'a').each(function() {
    $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/Black/g,"White") );
});
```

Original output:

```
<h1>The color is Black</h1>
<img src="/img/black.png" alt="Black">
```

Expected output:

```
<h1>The color is White</h1>
<img src="/img/black.png" alt="Black">
```

Sorry, I'm a bit of a beginner with JS but I can't figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: what's your original html code?

Comment: @dippas just added